# Corona iPhone Deployment Warning

Tags: iphone, ios, deployment, coronasdk

I have developed a game using corona. Now I get this warning while trying to build for iPhone using new provisioning profile.

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains            disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
failed to extract requirements data: 1

/Users/codemenmini2012-4/Desktop/ArcheryClassiciOS.app: invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)
failed to extract entitlements: 1

AssertMacros: entitlements_requested, At least need an application-identifier entitlements file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 879
 - (null)


warning: Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application.  Please make sure ArcheryClassiciOS is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned. (-19050)
/Users/codemenmini2012-4/Desktop/ArcheryClassiciOS.app/ArcheryClassiciOS: invalid signature (code or signature have been modified)- (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried revoking the Profile and requesting it again with a key from your machine? Apples profiles are annoying me quite often, too....